# Passing an => that calls a func instead of just passing the func itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arrow-functions

I'm giving myself a bit of a crash course on JavaScript so that I can learn React. I haven't done any dev work for many years so this may be a facepalm moment.

I am reading a blog post on useState(). I understand that if the parameter passed to useState() is a function, the function is only executed on the first render execution.

(EDIT: blog post is here https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/)

However, this confuses me:

```
const Message= () => {
   const messageState = useState( () => expensiveComputation() );
   /* ... */
}
```

In this example, why not just pass expensiveComputation to useState() like so?

```
const Message= () => {
   const messageState = useState( expensiveComputation );
   /* ... */
}
```

There are also some weird niggles about functions in Javascript that I don't think I'm understanding. For example, I've heard that arrow functions are executed when they are defined, but I've played with JSBin and I can't manage to prove that to myself in any way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Arrow functions are just functions, they are invoked / executed when you call them. usually calling /invoking them happens with `()`. You can also use `.call`.... A lot of people use arrows for everything because for them its more readable. I would say if this is something that is going to be inside a react component. either memoize that function or remove the arrow so you don't need to create a new function every render cycle

Comment: You seem to possibly be referencing [this blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/). If that's the case you need to add a link. And I'm not entirely sure the information in it is correct.

Comment: Indeed that's the post. I'll stick it in the OP. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the same in this particular case. The more general issue is the binding of `this`.

```
() => this.foo()
```

and

```
this.foo
```

are not the same, because "this" stays attached to the class in the first case and gets lost in the second case, so that when "foo()" is called in the second case, it won't be accessing the correct object as its "this".

It's generally regarded as a major design mistake of Javascript that `this` can be easily lost. The older-JS way to preserve `this` is with the `bind` method, i.e. `this.foo.bind(this)`. But in language design, it's not possible to redefine the meaning of code without breaking everyone's existing applications. When lambdas with => were introduced, `this` was handled in the more modern, lexical way that preserves `this`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thanks very much for your answer. I'm just confused, I guess, because I've seen several examples where this is done. So I've gotten into my head that there's a specific reason this is being done. But in this case there shouldn't be any issues with *this because it's in a functional component, thus it would be silly to use *this, correct?

Comment: on a react class `foo() {` is not bound with the parents context (the react state / props context), `foo = () => {` is bound. Use what you need to use depending on the use case.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with `this` in the OP's case: react hooks can't be called in class components so `this` isn't going to matter anyways.

Comment: @JaredSmith I know,  but considering the confusion is around when to and when not to use an arrow function, the scope is broader than just hooks. My comment on the question recommends memoizing it because its a functional component :)

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. I'm starting to wrap my head around it. I ended up reading about closures and such... this is starting to make much more sense. (JS is such a weird language after spending so long in C++/Java land!) Thanks again.